# Sobre escritura de variables en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario donde pregunto la cantidad de inputs que necesitan para agregar información. Este es el formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al generar el código para llenar los inputs me voy cuenta que tengo un error de programación que no se como solucionar, ya que mis variables son fijas y las sobre escribo.

```
<ul>
                        <?php /*Genera lista de prósitos para cada materia*/
                        if ($no_proposito1 == 1) {
                            printf('<li><input type="text" name="propositos1" placeholder="Descripción del proposito"></li>');
                        } else {
                            for ($i=1; $i <= $no_proposito1; $i++) {
                                printf('<li><input type="text" name="propositos1" placeholder="Descripción del proposito"></li>');
                            }

                        }

                         ?>
                    </ul>
```

Me gustaría saber si alguien me puede apoyar en como generar variables dinamicamente de acuerdo al input del usuario, mi limite para generar variables son 5.

PD: Soy nuevo programando y seguramente hay una solución mejor que la mia.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Podrías explicar lo que es `$no_proposito1` en tu código? es que lo tratas como si fuera un número en la 1ª parte del `if` y como su fuera un array en la segunda parte. Si se trata de generar inputs dinámicos puedes hacer que **sea siempre un array**, lo recorres y le asignas un número en cada iteracción a los identificadores. Así no tienes que preguntar si es uno, si tiene un solo elemento te creará un solo input, si tiene `5` te creará cinco. Tampoco se entiende del todo qué quieres decir con esto: *mi limite para generar variables son 5*

Comment: @A.Cedano `$no_proposito1` es un array donde tengo almacenado los números del 1 al 5 y si el usuario selecciona algún valor imprime la etiqueta `<li> </li>`. Ahora que lo mencionas mi `if` esta demás, basta con el `for` para generar los tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás trabajando con un array, puedes construir contenido dinámico así.

Veamos varios ejemplos:

#### El array tiene un sólo elemento:

```
$no_proposito=array(1);
$html="<ul>";
$i=1;
foreach ($no_proposito as $item)
{
    $html.="<li><input type=\"text\" name=\"propositos$i\" placeholder=\"Descripción proposito $i\"></li>";
/*Salimos cuando llegue a 5*/
if ($i++ == 5) break;

}

$html.="</ul>";

echo $html;
```

**Salida:**

```html
<ul>
  <li><input type="text" name="propositos1" placeholder="Descripción proposito 1"></li>
</ul>
```

---

#### El array tiene varios elementos y necesitamos los primeros cinco:

```
$no_proposito=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$html="<ul>";
$i=1;
foreach ($no_proposito as $item)
{
    $html.="<li><input type=\"text\" name=\"propositos$i\" placeholder=\"Descripción proposito $i\"></li>";
    if ($i++ == 5) break;

}

$html.="</ul>";

echo $html;
```

**Salida:**

```html
<ul>
  <li><input type="text" name="propositos1" placeholder="Descripción proposito 1"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="propositos2" placeholder="Descripción proposito 2"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="propositos3" placeholder="Descripción proposito 3"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="propositos4" placeholder="Descripción proposito 4"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="propositos5" placeholder="Descripción proposito 5"></li>
</ul>
```

---

#### También se puede usar la información que hay dentro del array

Sólo cambias esta línea:

```
$html.="<li><input type=\"text\" name=\"propositos$item\" placeholder=\"Descripción proposito $item\"></li>";
```

usando `$item` en lugar de `$i`. Ahí se usará el dato que haya en el array.

Comment: Adapté tu código al mio, pero me ayudó mucho la concatenación que me enviaste @A. Cedano, no tenía la menor idea de como hacer mis variables dinámicas. Tengo una última duda, previamente ya tengo una variable Array ( [materia] => Matemáticas ) como puedo agregar ese valor el nuevo array que se ha creado, revisando un poco la documentación de PHP puedo usar la función array_unshift pero no he podido implementarla.

Comment: Mi idea es poder agregar ese elemento de un arreglo pasado en la posición 0 para no perder la materia y me sirva de identificador.

Comment: @MarcosRugerio Stackoverflow funciona por pregunta. El objetivo es que una pregunta/respuesta siga siendo útil a futuros usuarios. Por eso cuando surge una nueva duda lo mejor es plantear una nueva pregunta con ella. Previamente hay que buscar en el sitio, no sea que algo parecido haya sido ya preguntado. Además tendrás la posibilidad de respuestas de varios usuarios, eligiendo la que más te convenga.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te propondria que utilizaras arrays en el html. Tendrias que conseguir generar esto:

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="text" name="propositos[]" placeholder="Descripción proposito 1"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="propositos[]" placeholder="Descripción proposito 2"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="propositos[]" placeholder="Descripción proposito 3"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="propositos[]" placeholder="Descripción proposito 4"></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="propositos[]" placeholder="Descripción proposito 5"></li>
</ul>
```

El corchete te permitirá enviar los "propositos" como un array, de manera que luego en tu php podrias leerlos asi:

```
$propositos = $_POST['propositos'];
```

y si haces un print_f($propositos) vas a obtener un array:

```
array() [
    0  => string()  ["proposito ejemplo 1"],
    1  => string()  ["proposito ejemplo 2"],
    2  => string()  null,
    3  => string()  ["proposito ejemplo 3"],
    4  => string()  ["proposito ejemplo 4"],

]
```

El null te lo pongo de ejemplo, porque no se si consideras el hecho de permitir propositos vacios. Si fuera asi entonces te podria llegar este caso.